# Как передать объект в ArrayAdapter, чтобы можно было вывести каждое поле объекта в определенном View элемента списка?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, listview, adapter

Допустим у меня есть

```
ArrayAdapter storyArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<NewStory>(this, R.layout.list_new_story_item, R.id.new_story_content, newStoryArrayList);
```

Если я правильно понимаю, то у меня здесь передается элемент из newStoryArrayList в макет list_new_story_item по идентификатору new_story_content. Соответственно, оно передает все поля объекта в один TextView. У меня же элемент списка состоит из многих полей и я хочу их привязать к разным TextView в элементе списка. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно написать свой адаптер и делать в нем все, что угодно, либо воспользоваться [SimpleAdapter](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/107-urok-48-ispolzuem-simpleadapter)